# Can't get CreateIpNetEntry API to work under Win7 64 bit

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

We have an application that sets up an IP address on a bit of embedded hardware. Part the the process is to setup and ARP mapping to map the new (but not yet assigned) address to the MAC address of the device.

Under XP this works perfectly and this code hasn't been touched since 2003. Under Win 7 64 bit (maybe 32 bit as well I haven't tried it) the call to CreateIpNetEntry returns a 0 success code but no entry is created in the ARP table. I'm running the exe as administrator so permissions shouldn't be the problem. I even tried adding a manifest file to force the requested execution level to requireAdministrator.

If it returned an error I might have something to go on but it returns a success code and doesn't do anything!

Comment: Are you explicitly using "Run as Administrator" or just running it while logged on as an administrator?  It's very easy to get manifests wrong.

Comment: Explicitly and also doing it via the app manifest file.  Even if I wasn't it should return a permissions error. The CreateIPNetEntry call instead returns a zero success code.  I've found several other posts on the net of other people having the same problem but no solutions but to avoid the CreateIpNetEntry call. On my system arp also fails so I can't even create a static entry. I can use netsh to create a route and then my code will work but it's not what I want to do.

Comment: Another tid bit. If I change the arp type from dynamic to static the call does create an entry. This appears to be some sort of limitation of Win 7. I actually can't find any way to create a dynamic entry in Win 7. Even NetSh that has a status=active option when creating an entry just ignores it and creates a static/permanent entry.

Comment: I finally just gave up and used a static entry. It just means it sticks around until the next reboot and that wasn't really a problem in this case.